# django admin add data with fixed value in some field

Tags: django, admin

```
class Facilites(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Objects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    facilityid = models.ForeignKey(Facilities)

class Admins(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    facilities = models.ManyToManyField(Facilities)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Admins.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

What i want is to have users (admins) only be able to add or modify "facilityid" in Objects to values specified in their Admins.facilities.
So if some user is named UserA and has facilities = ('FacA', 'FacB'), when he is adding a new object to DB, he shoudln't be able to add something like Object('Random object', 'FacC')

Also, he shouldn't be able to modify existing objects to facilities he doesn't belong to.

I have filtered the Objects with:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ObjectsAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(facitityid__id__in = request.user.get_profile().facilities.all())
```

so users can only see the object that belong to their facilities. But i have no idea how to prevent them from adding/editing object out of their facilities.

edit:

found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3048563/1421572

It turns out that ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey was the right answer in this situation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with either a pre-made facility list (i.e. You could create an integer field that is hooked to FACILITY_CHOICES for the user to select from.)

If only admins can do it then permissions sounds quite viable. You can also do form validation to check for errors against the db. Depending on how many facilities you have you may want a different approach.

You can do this same technique with a models.CharField as well. So perhaps assign a 3 letter facility code to each facility and require the entry to match one of the 3 letter strings. You could even have the list in a .txt file to read from. There are really so many ways to do this. I will provide an example of a pre-made facility list and accessing the facility a particular user belongs to from the api / template:

```
NYC_FACILITY = 0
LA_FACILITY = 1
ATL_FACILITY = 2

FACILITY_CHOICES = (
    (NYC_FACILITY, 'NYC'),
    (LA_FACILITY, 'LA'),
    (ATL_FACILITY, 'ATL'),

class Facility(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField(choices=FACILITY_CHOICES, default="NYC")

    class Meta:
        order_by = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = "facilities"
        verbose_name = "facility"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

As far as viewing the facilities page that a particular user belongs to you will have a m2m one to one or FK relationship between the objects. If FK or m2m relationship then you will have access to additional methods of that model type. get_related However, I'm not going to use get_related in my example. Once you are in an instance you then have access to entry_set.

```
# models.py
from django.auth import User
class Person(User):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    facility_loc = models.ForeignKey('Facility') # ForeignKey used assuming only one person can belong to a facility.
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/%s/%s/" % self.facility_loc % self.slug

# views.py - TemplateView is automatically given a context variable called params which parses data from the URL. So, I'll leave the regex in the URLConf up to you.

class UserFacilityView(TemplateView):
    model = Facility
    template_name = "user_facility.html"
```

Now in your template you should be able to access facility_set from a User instance or user_set from a facility instance.

Comment: List of facilities IS in Facilities table in db. Each admin should be able to belong to any and all of facilities, but be allowed to edit and add only object belonging to his facilities.
Each object belongs only to one facility.
And i would like that in django admin interface.